# Why can't my child class use the inherited function from the parent class?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Javascript and nodejs (node_modules?).
Why can't the Student child class access the socialSecNum setter from the parent class? The regex function works just fine when I use it from the parent class?

```
class Person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, sosialSecNum) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.sosialSecNum = sosialSecNum;
  }
  get firstName() {
    return this._firstName;
  }
  set firstName(newFirstName) {
    this._firstName = newFirstName;
  }
  get lastName() {
    return this._lastName;
  }
  set lastName(newLastName) {
    this._lastName = newLastName;
  }
  get sosialSecNum() {
    return this._socialSecNum;
  }
  set sosialSecNum(newSocialSecNum) {
    const regExTest = /\d{6}[+-A]\d{3}[0-9ABCDEFHJKLMNPRSTUVWXY]/;
    if (newSocialSecNum.match(regExTest)) {
      this._socialSecNum = newSocialSecNum;
    } else {
      this._socialSecNum = '123456-123A';
    }
  }
  printing() {
    console.log(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + ' is a person whos social security number is ' + this.sosialSecNum);
  }
};

const dude = new Person('jack', 'jacker', '123456-123B');
dude.printing();


class Student extends Person {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, sosialSecNum, ECTS) {
    super(firstName, lastName, ECTS);
    this.ECTS = ECTS;
  }
  get ECTS() {
    return this._ECTS;
  }
  set ECTS(newECTS) {
    this._ECTS = newECTS;
  }
  printing() {
    console.log(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + ' is a Student whos social security number is ' + this.socialSecNum + ' and who has ' + this._ECTS + ' ECTS points.');
  }
}

const dudette = new Student('jill', 'jiller', '123456-123B', 5);
dudette.printing();
```

The error I get:

jack jacker is a person whos social security number is 123456-123B
c:\Users...
if (newSocialSecNum.match(regExTest)) {
^

TypeError: newSocialSecNum.match is not a function
at Student.set sosialSecNum [as sosialSecNum] (c:...

Comment: Typo: `ECTS` instead of `sosialSecNum` in the `super()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the number 5 as the social security number in the constructor. Numbers do not have a `match()` function on their prototype so you are getting the "is not a function" error. Change your code to pass the social security number string instead and it will work.

```
  constructor(firstName, lastName, sosialSecNum, ECTS) {
    super(firstName, lastName, sosialSecNum);
    this.ECTS = ECTS;
  }
```